# List all files in directory in Libgdx using external destination

Tags: java, android, libgdx, filesystems

I am currently trying to list all of the files in a directory using libgdx file systems and as I get into the directories I want to view the list function starts to return a list of length 0 even though I am positive it is not empty.

I was testing on my android phone and was going step by step deeper into the phone. These are the lines I used to check the list and how many items it returned. Please let me know what I am doing wrong or a work around thank you.

```
Gdx.files.absolute(".").list().length()               //Returned 63
Gdx.files.absolute("./storage").list().length         //Returned 4
Gdx.files.absolute(./storage/emulated).list().length  //Returned 0
```

Again the path ./storage/emulated is definitely not empty. Do i need to request a special permission to access this area? Please lmk. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe because you didn't put quote in third line of code where it should be  "./storage/emulated"

Comment: I did in the actual code this was just a transfer error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting Make it clear for Android your targetSdkVersion is less than 23 if not take permission at run time by user before proceeding any work related to your File IO. For current targetSdkVersion check your defaultConfig of android `build.gradle` file, if not present their check `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Add this permission to `AndroidMainfest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I understand External Destination is address where we keep our own data like video, music and all.

`Gdx.files.getExternalStoragePath()` give path `/storage/emulated/0/` in Android and User Directory on Desktop like this `C:\Users\Abhishek Aryan\`

We want to all files inside External Storage(External Storage doesn't mean SD Card). `/storage/emulated/0/` represent inbuilt Storage.

```
FileHandle dirHandle = Gdx.files.external("/");    

for (FileHandle entry: dirHandle.list()) {
     System.out.println(entry.toString());
}
```

By recursion you can get all files and folder inside your storage.

Comment: Thank you I think I was just missing that permission!